# Android: How to add listener to hardware menu button?

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to add a click listener to the menu hardware button. Currently I'm just putting my onclick logic into the onCreatePanelMenu-method and return false. But that just feels wrong.

Is there a more clean way?

The code currently looks like that:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "HALLO!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Catch the key event inside [`onKeyDown()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) and add your action there.

Sample:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            doSomething();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```

*Just replace `doSomething()` with your functionality/methods.*

Comment: Return false in my implementation.  I'm using key to show / hide status & action bar.

Answer (score 4):

If you need some code samples you can try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.preferences:
            showPreferencesActivity();
            return true;
        case R.id.logOff:
            logOff();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The above should be pretty self explanotory - it sets a menu with the options to show preferences or log off.

/Nicklas

Answer (score 1):

try this 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu

> If you want to change the Options Menu any time after it's first
>   created, you must override the onPrepareOptionsMenu() method

so the system will call `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` every time the user clicks `Menu` key

Comment: I don't use a menu, I just want to use the hardware button to toggle a slider menu.

Comment: sorry, i didnt get the question well, see @alextsc answer, its what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`onContextItemSelected`

`onOptionsItemSelected`

I beleive are what you are looking for.