# Alert Dialog with setCancleable(false) I cannot show the Menu

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I use modal alert dialogs by calling `setCancelable(false);` By doing this the *BACK* hardware button is disabled. But unfortunately this is also true for the *MENU* hardware button. So the user does not have access to the option menu. I am using a Samsung Galaxy Tab3 with Android 4.4.2

How can I change this? Alternatively: Is there a possibility to catch the BACK button pressed event in a `DialogFragment`?

Comment: You should be able to just override onBackPressed from the activity that is hosting the dialog. I haven't tested it, but should work.

Comment: well if you show a dialog and you set it cancelable false...so the user waits for some data to be loaded. Why would he want to access the menu??

Comment: there are life cycles in a dialog fragment.. probably use a boolean to switch to true when in oncreate and switch to false when onstop is called..cool logic.. so anytime the boolean is true.. do nothing..if its false call your super.onbackpressed function..

Comment: If I call setCancelable(true) then I can -of course- press the back button BUT the onBackPressed() method in my activity is not invoked. My architecture is: FragmentActivity -> Fragment-> DialogFragment

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the trick :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            doSomething();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```

(See more here : [Android: How to add listener to hardware menu button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137325/android-how-to-add-listener-to-hardware-menu-button))

Comment: In a DialogFragment I can NOT overwrite onKeyDown(). This method is neither available on DialogFragment or Fragment. So this is not possible

Comment: Try to override it on your activity and build a callback