# Overflow menu showing on bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-menu

In my activity when i press three dots, overflow menu shows normally like this [image]

But when i long press "Recent apps" button it shows on bottom of screen like this

[image]

XML for menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_bar_button"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings" />

</menu>
```

Code for menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchButton = menu.findItem(R.id.search_bar_button);
    searchView = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) searchButton.getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class)));

    return true;
}
```

I am using support Toolbar, and it happens on all versions of android.
Also my theme is using NoActionBar is it because of that ?

Comment: Do you have hardware key for menu? You need something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307214/how-to-force-overflow-menu-in-actionbar-using-actionbarsherlock-on-4-0-devices

Comment: No i dont have, but when you long press Recent app button it should open overflow menu. And i am using Toolbar.

Comment: add optionmenu code

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: @JozefDochan You don't have hard ware button. Sure. But calling your "long press Recent app button" makes the same, like Menu hardware call (action of MenuItem). Then you need to override this call, ad mentioned above. Like here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137325/android-how-to-add-listener-to-hardware-menu-button

Comment: @GensaGames you should add it as answer so i can give you a bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have hard ware button. Sure. But calling your "long press Recent app button" makes the same, like Menu hardware call (action of MenuItem). Then you need to override this call. Also examples [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137325/android-how-to-add-listener-to-hardware-menu-button)

Catch the key event inside `onKeyDown()` and add your action there.
Sample:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            doSomething();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to catch the menu key and open the overflow menu. Add this to your Activity or AppCompatActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            mToolbar.showOverflowMenu();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```